# Proof: If $7\mid 4a$, then $7\mid a$

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Working my way through Hammack's "Book of Proof" (I'm terribly rusty).  One of the exercises is as follows:
Suppose $a$ is an integer.  If $7\mid 4a$, $7\mid a$.

The book asks for a direct proof.  I believe I have one, but it is a different one from the answer section.  Would someone be willing to verify it is valid?

Thanks.

Suppose $7\mid 4a$, where $a$ is an integer.

Then, $4a = 7b$, where $b$ is an integer.  Therefore, $a = (7/4)b$.

Since $a$ is defined as an integer, $b$ must be a multiple of $4$; let $b = 4c$, where $c$ is an integer.

Therefore, $a = 7c$.

As such, $7\mid a$ is equal to $7\mid 7c$ which is obviously true.

Comment: If you deduce from $a = (7/4)b$ that $b$ is a multiple of $4$, you might as well just start from the fact that $(4/7)a$ is an integer and deduce $a$ is a multiple of $7$.

Comment: A direct proof: If $7|4a$ then $7|2\times 4a=8a=a+7a$. Therefore $a+7a=7K$ for some integer $K$. From this you get $a=7(K-a)$.

Comment: I would omit the last sentence, which is a bit confusing, but this looks nearly fine. However, it is important to explain why you can conclude that $b$ is a multiple of $4$. If you knew that $a=(6/4)b$, you could not be sure, for example.

Comment: Your step that $4\mid b$ is mere assertion. Try keeping your argument in integers (so don't apply intuitions about fractions like $\frac{7}{4}.$

Comment: Is it assertion, though, if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is one of the premises of the proof?  (Edit to add: Not snarkiness, genuinely asking.  As I said, I'm very rusty on proofs.)

Comment: @sphere Did the book cover [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) at that point? Dit it cover unique factorization?

Comment: @dxiv No.  Relatively little, it starts with a minimal toolset.

Comment: @mathworker21 That would seem to shorten things.  That being said, that would seem subject to the same problem in Thomas Andrews' comment, wouldn't it?

Comment: @sphere Then what properties of divisibility and/or prime numbers are you allowed to use? Note that if you replace $7$ with $6$ in the statement of the problem then the implication no longer holds.

Comment: @dxiv Basically, the definition of $a \vert b$ (that $b = ca, c \in \mathbb{Z}$), and nothing on primes.

Comment: Addendum: I realize there are a variety of ways to prove this (the author of the text uses a proof based on the properties of even and odd numbers), and I'm not looking for examples (although it is neat to see different ways of going about it).  My question is whether my proof is valid - one commenter above stated that it relies on mere assertion that $4 \vert b$, while another suggests that it's okay.  Is there any consensus?  Thanks again.

Comment: @sphere No, your argument is incorrect. You are essentially using what you want to prove to get to the conclusion.

Comment: @sphere The problem with your proof is the line `Since a is defined as an integer, b must be a multiple of 4` While that may be intuitively obvious, you still need to *prove* it somehow, it's not enough to just *state* it.

Comment: @orole. Thanks. Followup: If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is one of the premises of the proof, why is it unacceptable to use that premise to infer that $4 \vert b$?  Don't we generally accept the premises?

Comment: @sphere Try the same reasoning with $6$ and $4$ instead of with $7$ and $4$. Your reasoning would still conclude that $b$ is a multiple of $4$, but that is not necessarily true. So, what is special about $7$ and $4$ that is not valid for $6$ and $4$? At some point in the reasoning you'll have to use that special property.

Comment: Thank you to all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by several people in the comments, your proof is circular. At the point where you deduce that $b$ must be a multiple of $4$, you're essentially using what you have to prove.

Try the same reasoning with 6 and 4 instead of with 7 and 4. Your reasoning would still conclude that b is a multiple of 4, but that is not necessarily true. So, what is special about 7 and 4 that is not valid for 6 and 4? At some point in the reasoning you'll have to use that special property.

I would use the fact that $2 \cdot 4 - 7 = 1$.

Assume $7 \mid 4a$. This means that $$4a = 7k$$ for some integer $k$. Now turn that $4$ into a $1$ by multiplying it by $2$ and subtracting $7$: $$2 \cdot 4a - 7a = 2 \cdot 7k - 7a,$$ i.e., $$a = 7(2k -a),$$ so $$7 \mid a.$$

Note that the actual reason that this claim holds is that $\gcd(4, 7) = 1$. 
This is equivalent to saying that there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $4x + 7y = 1$ (namely, $x = 2$ and $y = -1$).

Answer (score 0):

I like this:
 $7 | 4a$, hence $7$ divides $2\cdot(4a) = 8a$.  Of course $7|7a$.  And thus $7$ divides $8a-7a = a$.

Answer (score 0):

> Then, $4a = 7b$, where $b$ is an integer.

You could shorten the rest to: it follows that $a = 8a-7a=14b-7a=7(2b-a)\,$, so $7 \mid a\,$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $7|4a.$

Euclid's Lemma:

If a prime $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Since $7$ does not divide $4$, $7$ divides $a$.